# Are two 6x6 posts adequate to support a stone or brick wall in an earthquake zone?

Tags: wood, support

Will 2 (one on either side) of treated 6 inch by 3 inch wood beams set 3 feet into concrete with a 12 inch footer support a rock or brick wall that weighs say 2000 lbs if the wood is properly mounted to the wall. The wall is 7 feet long and 6 feet high 15 inches wide. How much would wind be a factor?

```
 ________________________________________
|  ____                            ____  |
| |    |                          |    | |
| |____|                          |____| |
|________________________________________|
```

Comment: Support how? Rock walls usually support themselves.

Comment: Inserted so the bricks surround it

Comment: We live in California so I am worried about possible seismic activity

Comment: Then I'd say your plan is reasonable. If you're designing for earthquake tolerance wind isn't remotely a concern.

Comment: Yes kind of but I thought if I had more then one wall perhaps a notch 3 inches in into each section so they could share posts

Comment: I would be worried the wood would rot in contact or sheer with movement. I would use rebar / wire, I always use reinforcement when over 4' as it was a code requirement at one of the houses I had just don't remember which state.

Answer (score 1):

No, code does not allow masonry, of any kind, to be supported by wood:

> **2104.1.6 Support on wood.** Masonry shall not be supported on wood girders or other forms of wood construction except as permitted in [Section 2304.12](http://www.optasoft.com/applications/codes/2006IBC/HTMLHelp/2304.12.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure this applies. Any brick wall on a modern home is "supported" using brick ties attaching it to the wood-framed wall. I think the code cited refers to masonry being directly borne by wood, vertically.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I think this is for “Long-term vertical loading”. In fact, your reference to Section 2104.1.6 mentions “horizontal supports” as an “exception”.